# Django channels live chat save sent messages

Tags: django, websocket, model, channel

So I have a Django app in which I used channels to implement live chat. My consumer looks like this:

import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = self.scope["user"]
        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'user': username.username
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        user=event['user']
        print(user)
        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'user':user
        }))
```

So I am looking for a way to save the sent messages (because currently they are lost on refresh). I have created a Messages model that has a CharField for the message text. I think I can save new messages if I do this in my chat_message function:

```
new_message=Messages(text=message)
new_nessage.save()
```

My question is how do I preload the last 10 messages whenever a user gets connected to the chat?

Comment: I would suggest creating an ajax call once the connection has established. Also store a timestamp with the new messages, and then slice for last ten when using filter like ```Messages.objects.filter()[:10]```.

Comment: I am really new to coding in general. I have thought about the slice for the last 10 messages and I thought of doing it using Messages.objects.order_by(*a date field that I am going to add to the model)[:10]. However can you explain the other part - the ajax call (if you have some free time of course). A link to a tutorial about this ajax call would be greatly appreciated too if you don't have time to explain it!

Comment: Where you've defined the WebSocket in your template. Create a function ```socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {}``` (doc here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onopen). Then inside the function create an ajax called back to the server with the channel group id (WebSocket.url). Then filter your Messages in your views.py and return JSONResponse. How to do AJAX is here (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html). Then the data from the ajax success can be loaded into your html.

Comment: Hey. So I have a new problem now. In the chat_message function I am doing the following:

new_message=Message(sender=myUser, rec=otherUser, text=message, room=getIDS)
new_message.save()

But now every message saves twice - 1 time for each user in the chatroom. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Never mind, fixed it - just moved the code to the receive function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in order to do this, I ended up saving my message to the database in the "receive" function (because if you save it in the chat_message one it's saved 1 time for each active user). Then in order to preload messages I used an AJAX call every time a websocket is opened in order to get the 10 most recent messages using a python function and then I passed the messages back as a JsonResponse (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html scroll down to the AJAX requests part of this article and take a look at signup.html, urls.py and views.py files in this order for reference).

Comment: Nice! https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django#websocket-consumers has a good example on how to do precisely that.